# xamarin.forms - how to make ViewCell height dynamic

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with HasUnevenRows = true.

There are buttons within my ViewCell that modify its contents.  When this happens, it causes the ViewCell to overlap with its neighboring ViewCell.  When the ViewCell is scrolled out of view and then back into view again, the heights have updated and everything looks as it should.

Is there a way to update the ViewCell dynamically so that the height changes with the changing contents of the Cell?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I have experienced before. I believe it is a bug in Xamarin Forms. Make sure you have tried the latest XF version as well in case it was fixed in a recent update.

Change your ListView to `CachingStrategy="RetainElement"` and it will work but you lose the visualization of your ListView.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I passed `ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement` as an argument to my ListView's constructor, but it didn't change the behavior of the ViewCells in the list.